# How to use list of symbols for sympy calculation in python?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using python 3.7 on Spyder. Here is my simple code to store string elements ['a','b'] in a list L as sympy symbols. As output, I have new list L with two Symbols [a,b] in it. But when I try to use these symbols in my calculation I get an error saying a & b are not defined. Any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Basically, what I want to do is use string elements in a list as symbols for sympy calculations. Any suggestions on other methods to do this are welcomed. Thank you.

```
    import sympy as sm
    L=['a','b']
    print(L)
    for j in range(len(L)):
        L[j] = sm.symbols(L[j])
    B=sm.solve(a**2 - 1, a)
    print(B)
```

Here is the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/bhise/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/bhise/.spyder-py3')
['a', 'b']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-43-6826047bb7df>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/bhise/.spyder-py3/temp.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/bhise/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\bhise\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\bhise\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/bhise/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    B=sm.solve(a**2 - 1, a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: It works with no problems with python 3.8.2. Perhaps more information is needed, including versions, exact error messages.

Comment: I have added the information you asked for

Comment: Did you import a?  from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b

Comment: Actually I don't want to define symbols in code itself. I want to take input from a user and then assign them as symbols just like we do: x = Symbol('x') But here 'x' will be the user input

Comment: it seems to work with strings as well.
In [17]: sm.solve('a**3 - 1', a)                                                                    
Out[17]: [1, -1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2, -1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2]

Comment: Oh! yeah! It worked with a string.  But in sympy document equation was entered without quotes. Nevermind! It worked. Thanks alot!

Comment: I guess you're supposed to use sm.solve(sm.symbols('a**3 - 1'), a) but I dunno :)
Um, one might assume that sm.symbols would do some linting or cleaning of user input, but needs research.

Comment: This is a near duplicate of the question to which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60471208/1089161) was given.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your symbols just the way you want to use it.

ex.
[a,b,c] = sm.symbols('a b c')

Now you can use a,b,c in your code.

The way you are using it in L[j] = sm.symbols(L[j]), L[j] doesn't really take **a** as a variable.

Or in your case you can use it:

```
from sympy import sm

L=['a','b']
print(L)

for j in range(len(L)):
    locals()[L[j]] = sm.symbols(L[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b']
>>> a, b = map(Symbol, L)
>>> type(a)
<class′sympy.core.symbol.Symbol′>
```

And then use `a` and `b` wherever you want.