# Dynmaic way to make symbols in sympy or making symbols dynamically

Tags: python, dynamic, sympy

For me it is necessary to **make symbols** in my code, So after building them(**made by code** in a list):

[W, U, V, x]

or

W, U, V, x

I need to turn them into sympy.symbols in a dynamic way not manually by coder :

x, y = symbols('x y') or symbols('x, y')

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with `x, y = symbols('x y')`? I realise the symbols are created dynamically but any code that needs `x` and `y` as local Python variables could only be written by someone who knew what symbols there should be so why can't that person just write `x, y = symbols('x y')` at the start of their code?

Comment: It doesn't matter what strings are passed, but how each string can be a symbol dynamically is my problem.

Comment: We are struggling to understand your goal. Please, take the time to edit the question and provide a minimal working example of what you would like to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expose the symbols in the module as mentioned by Frank C on [sympy unknown assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469399/sympy-unknown-assignment/60471208#60471208)

```
def symbol_references(in_list):
    for e in in_list:
        globals()[e] = Symbol(e)

symbol_references(['x', 'y'])
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```